# Dynamically style a mat-tab property from an Angular 6 component

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material-6

I have a `mat-tab-group` with two tabs -  Basic search and Advance Search. Since the advanced search has a lot more form fields, I'd like to dynamically modify the `max-height` property of the `.mat-tab-body-content` class.

```html
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="tabChanged($event)">
 <mat-tab label="Basic">
  <ng-template matTabContent>
   

  <!-- .. -->

  </ng-template>
 </mat-tab>
 <mat-tab label="Advanced">
  <div>
   <ng-template matTabContent #advSearchTab>
    <form [formGroup]="searchForm" (ngSubmit)="search()"  >
    
     <!-- ... -->
     
    </form>
   </ng-template>
  </div>
 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

And when it renders to the DOM, Angular injects this content class:

```
  <div class="mat-tab-body-content ng-trigger ng-trigger-translateTab" style="transform: none;">
```

I have some scss which I would like to change dynamically in my component ts code.

Here's the scss settings I have currently for the `max-height` and `overflow-y` values:

```html
$advanced-search-panel-max-height: 800px;
$advanced-search-panel-overflow-y: auto;

:host ::ng-deep .mat-tab-body-content{  
  max-height: $advanced-search-panel-max-height;
  padding:5px;
  overflow-y: $advanced-search-panel-overflow-y;
}
```

On a laptop this `max-height` with `auto` doesn't show a scrollbar (i.e. you would normally see the Submit/Clear button at the bottom), which causes the content to become hidden at the bottom. For this reason I'd like to dynamically modify those two styles.

[image]
Can I somehow assign those scss vars within my component code, or do I have to go with an `ElementRef` type ?

Comment: Why not just use `<mat-tab-group [dynamicHeight]="true">`?

Comment: @G.Tranter - I even tried that again just now, but I'm guessing that the parent component is causing this behavior. Even putting `overflow-y: scroll;` on the `    .mat-tab-body-content` selector shows a white bar but it does not scroll.

Comment: It would probably help a lot if you could share a complete working example on StackBlitz. The code you shared isn't right - the SASS var names don't match up between definition and usage - so it's hard to know if that is the actual problem or if it was a merely a copy error.

Comment: my mistake - the sass vars start with `$advanced-search-panel`.

Comment: By default, the mat-tab-body-content class already has overflow set to auto, so I don't really understand why you think you need to set that. Under normal use, if you want a vertical scrollbar to appear inside the tab, then you just need to restrict the height of mat-tab-group.

Comment: setting `:host .mat-tab-group {
  max-height: 100%;
}` seems to do the trick. I'm testing on desktop and laptop...You may add as the final answer.

Comment: Thank-you @bob.mazzo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the mat-tab-body-content class already has overflow set to auto, so you shouldn't need to set that. Under normal use, if you want a vertical scrollbar to appear inside the tab, then you just need to restrict the height of mat-tab-group.